# Rails Print Receipt with nested attributes using Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I want to print a receipt involving information on a form that includes nested attributes and I decided to use prawn

My controller looks like this:

```
def show
  visit = Household.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
      pdf = VisitPdf.new(visit)
      send_data pdf.render, filename: "visit_#{visit.id}.pdf",
         type: "application/pdf",
         disposition: "inline"
    end
 end
end
```

It works and I get the pdf using this button (in haml)

```
 = link_to 'Print Order', household_path(household, format: "pdf"), class: 'btn btn-inverse btn-info'
```

My Receipt is for a household that has a nested_attribute consisting of a visit with several field and I want the fields from the visit to print on the pdf

For my Household the following works up to the point where I deal with visits:

```
class VisitPdf < Prawn::Document

  def initialize(household)
    super()
    @household = household
    @visit = household.visit
    # visit_id
    visit_date
    household_name
    house_count
    starch
    special
  end

  def household_name
    move_down 10
    text "Household: #{@household.name}"
  end

  def house_count
    text "Neighbors: #{@household.neighbors.count}"
  end


 def visit_date
   text "Date: #{@visit.visited_on.strftime('%B %d, %Y')}"
 end
```

@visit = household.visit doesn't work. With the pdf I am rendering what is in my view so the instance variable should be available to me (note I am using decent exposure which is why I have the @household = household)

Visit fields are inserted via cocoon as follows:

```
= link_to_add_association( 'New Visit', f, :visits , class: 'btn btn-success btn-large', :render_options => {wrapper: 'bootstrap' },:force_non_association_create => true)
```

With the Inputs:

```
 = f.input  :visited_on, label: 'Date of Visit', default: Date.today, order: [:month, :day],input_html: { class: 'span2' }
```

How do I access my Visit instance variables?

Comment: If your associations are okay, it seems fine. Wht does it return?

Comment: It crashes - I am thinking @visit = household.visits[1] or visits[0] is closer   - it doesn't crash but doesn't return anything

Comment: you can use raise or log to inspect `household` . Then in console you can find if that household.visits exist. I guess the relation is household has_many :visits, otherwise nothing wrong with this